# Buildkite how to mount single files in docker agent

Tags: buildkite

I want to configure a pipeline to run my tests. The tests are in a docker-compose file. Inside my Buildkite agent, I cannot mount single files.

I want to mount the source directory and individual config files. My docker-compose works fine in other environments.

What should I do?

For example:

```
 docker run -it --rm -v /test.sh:/test.sh busybox cat /test.sh
 cat: read error: Is a directory
```

Comment: Does `/test.sh` exist on your host machine? I believe if it doesn't, then docker just creates an empty directory at that path which may be why your `cat` fails.

Comment: Yes it does. Test.sh does exist

Comment: You can try it out too. You will probably get the same result as me.

Comment: What version of docker are you using?

Comment: Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6

Comment: docker run -e BUILDKITE_AGENT_TOKEN="" --name buildkite-agent -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock buildkite/agent:ubuntu

Comment: I use this command to start my agent.

Answer (score 1):

The Docker agent uses the `/buildkite` directory in it's Docker container for the build checkouts, but that usually doesn't exist outside on the Docker host. So when you use `-v` it's trying to mount `/buildkite` from the host machine, which doesn't exist, and so you end up with an empty directory mounted to `/test.sh`.

One workaround is to mount in a directory from the host machine to `/buildkite`, for example:

```
docker run \
  -v /buildkite:/buildkite \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  buildkite/agent start ...
```

And then inside your build you should be able to run the following:

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD/test.sh:/test.sh" busybox cat /test.sh
```

(`$PWD` will be something like `/buildkite/builds/agent123/pipeline123`)

If you want to use something other than `/buildkite` on the host machine, e.g. `/usr/local/var/buildkite-agent`, you mount it through the same way but you also need to configure the agent to use that path:

```
docker run \
  -v /usr/local/var/buildkite-agent:/usr/local/var/buildkite-agent: \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -e BUILDKITE_BUILD_PATH=/usr/local/var/buildkite-agent/builds \
  -e BUILDKITE_HOOKS_PATH=/usr/local/var/buildkite-agent/hooks \
  -e BUILDKITE_PLUGINS_PATH=/usr/local/var/buildkite-agent/plugins \
  buildkite/agent start ...
```

Hope that helps!